# Why hasn't Starkiller been referenced in another source?

Tags: star-wars

Starkillers only appearances to date are Force Unleashed and Force Unleashed II. Why is this? Why hasn't he at least be mentioned in another source, its like he's completely isolated from the rest of the Expanded Universe.

Comment: This is highly speculative.

Comment: "Starkiller" was a surname associated with Luke an Anakin used in early drafts in ANH and wasn't reused until the games came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I think the key to that answer would lie in *The Force Unleashed III*, which I'm not sure if LucasArts will make.

That said, with the way *Force Unleashed II* ends, I think Lucas Licensing owes it to Star Wars fans to provide a TFU 3, as a book a least, if they are not going to do a game.

How can you leave a story hanging, ie Vader captured by the Rebellion and not reveal how he escapes to attack the Tantive IV in Episode IV?

Anyway...my guess is either Starkiller flees to the Outer Rim with Juno, or, Juno dies and at some point Starkiller dies as well (by choice).

Another interesting note, according to Wookieepedia, is that the original Starkiller dies in TFU. The Starkiller in TFU2 is indeed a clone and not a resurrected Starkiller. They also hint that the Dark Apprentice (the evil clone) does exist, even in the "good" ending, but is just not revealed.

Again, all these loose ends, I think begs for a TFU 3, at least to tie up the story.